# finding xpath for dynamic element

Tags: selenium, testng

I am trying to find the xpath of a dynamic element. Entering the below xpath returns 10 elements.

`//div[contains(@class,'gallery_grid_image_caption
gallery_grid_image_caption_padding')]/p`

One of the those elements has a text called 'Add Category'.

```html
<div class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content">
  <div class="gallery_grid_image_caption gallery_grid_image_caption_padding">
    <div class="gallery_grid_image_menu" />
    <p class="uk-text-truncate uk-text-upper uk-text-center add_category">Add category</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select this element and click on that.

So I tried the below:

`//div[contains(@class,'gallery_grid_image_caption gallery_grid_image_caption_padding')]/p[contains(text()='Add Category')]`

But it's not returning the element.

Please advice as to where i am going wrong?

Comment: in `xpath` contains always work with `,`.... means in your `xpath` this line `p[contains(text()='Add Category')]` to be `p[contains(text(),'Add category')]`....and it's `category`...`c` is in lowercase here..

Answer (score 1):

Please try this `XPath`:

```
//p[text()="Add category"]
```

P.S. Please note that `contains` used in this way:

```
//p[contains(text(),'Add category')]
```